# tuple index out of bounds, variadic template

Tags: c++, windows

[DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/N1tp3JG5u)

How I could read the `args` of this variadic template, as it can be any number of arguments?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum class traceErr
{
   err1, err2
};

template <typename... Args>
void TraceErr(traceErr err, Args&&... args)
{
    auto pack = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    std::string str;

    switch (err)
    {
    case traceErr::err1:
        str = "Err: " + std::to_string(std::get<0>(pack));
    break;

    case traceErr::err2:
        str = "Err: " + std::to_string(std::get<0>(pack)) + " "
        + std::get<1>(pack);
    break;
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    TraceErr(traceErr::err1, 1);
    TraceErr(traceErr::err2, 2, "etc");  
}
```

In the example above I'm getting these errors:

`static_assert failed: 'tuple index out of bounds`

`'get': no matching overload function found`

Because the number of args being passed are different, how i could 'fix' it to work with any number of args?

Answer (score 0):

For every specialization of `TraceErr` the whole function body is compiled and must be valid. If you're providing only 2 parameters and therefore the tuple size is 1, the expression

```
std::get<1>(pack)
```

is invalid.

The only way to ignore this kind of issue and keep the statement for both specializations would be to use `if constexpr`, but this requires the first function parameter to be changed to a template parameter.

```
enum class traceErr
{
   err1, err2
};

template <traceErr err, typename... Args>
void TraceErr(Args&&... args)
{
    auto pack = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    std::string str;

    if constexpr (err == traceErr::err1)
    {
        str = "Err: " + std::to_string(std::get<0>(pack));
    }
    else
    {
        str = "Err: " + std::to_string(std::get<0>(pack)) + " "
             + std::get<1>(pack);
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    TraceErr<traceErr::err1>(1);
    TraceErr<traceErr::err2>(2, "etc");  
}
```

But why use `std::tuple` here at all? Just use a fold expression:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void TraceErr(T&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << "Err: " << std::forward<T>(arg);
    ((std::cout << ' ' << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    TraceErr(1);
    TraceErr(2, "etc");
}
```

(Note: You could generate a fold expression for creating a string, but it may be preferrable to avoid the dynamic memory allocation required and directly write the results to the output stream.)

Comment: I would like to keep the switch and do something according to the value of the enum, maybe passing the second parameter as a struct?

Comment: @Katia You could simply add another parameter to the front of the parameter list, if you're doing something other than determining the argument count with the value.

Comment: If you want to keep syntax in your `main` function you could also apply a little trick: create a template with a template parameter, and create constant objects using that template to allow template argument deduction to deduce the enum constant: `namespace impl { enum class traceErr ...; template<traceErr>struct Tag{}; } namespace traceErr { constexpr impl::Tag<impl::traceErr::err1> err1; ... } template<impl::traceErr err, ...> void TraceErr(impl::traceErr::Tag<err>, ...)`

Comment: fabian I didnt understand the trick you mentioned

Comment: @Katia Let's use a simpler example: You want to create an `std::array<int, N>` using a function `f` with `N` depending on the input, but you want to call the function as `f(One); f(Two); f(Five);`. You can go with constants that contain the information of the desired size in the type: `template<size_t N> struct SizeTag{}; constexpr SizeTag<1> One;constexpr SizeTag<2> Two;constexpr SizeTag<5> Five;template<size_t N> std::array<int, N> f(SizeTag<N>) {return {};}` and when passing one of the constants the compiler deduces N. Using namespaces you make the constants useable as if they were an enum.